# how to call job after insert into table oracle?

Tags: oracle

i have a table i want call a job after two minute from every  insert into table ?

Comment: What rate of inserts do you expect this table to have?  Could you have a single job that runs periodically and looks for any unprocessed rows whose insertion date is more than two minutes ago?  That's going to be far more efficient unless you know that people are only rarely going to insert a row in this table.

Comment: And do what? Why 2 minutes - are you waiting for something else to happen? You can use dbms_scheduler for creating jobs, in order to do it safely within a transaction you could decouple it with a dbms_aq advanced queue so that the request is only made once the original insert is committed, you’d then have something constantly checking the queue and create jobs with dbms_scheduler. It’s a lot of work, and you’d probably be better off with a different solution completely once your real requirements are understood.

Comment: What do you expect when the user issue a ROLLBACK command? (maybe even later than 2 minutes afterwards? )

Comment: @Andrew Sayer , when insert a new record into  table i call web-service  to send alert to mobile through the Telecommunications Company  ,after send this alert  i want call another web service to get the number of mobiles that have successfully scheduled the alert .

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit , thanks i don't use rollback , "pragma  autonomous transaction"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, there are quite a few "ifs" (see comments).

Anyway, you asked a question and here's one option which answers it.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(20), datum date);

Table created.
```

A dummy procedure which doesn't do anything smart, just re-inserts the same row, increments `ID` column value and sets a  new timestamp to test whether it fired 2 minutes after the insert):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_id test.id%type) is
  2  begin
  3    insert into test (id, name, datum)
  4      select id + 1,
  5             name,
  6             sysdate
  7      from test
  8      where id = par_id;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Trigger creates a database job using simple `DBMS_JOB` package; it calls previously created `P_TEST` procedure 2 minutes after the insert.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_test
  2    after insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_job number;
  6  begin
  7     dbms_job.submit (
  8        job         => l_job,
  9        what        =>    'begin p_test ('
 10                       || :new.id
 11                       || '); end;',
 12        next_date   => sysdate + 2 / (24 * 60),
 13        interval    => null);
 14  end trg_ai_test;
 15  /

Trigger created.
```

Setting date format (so that you'd know *what is what* in the `datum` column):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from test;

no rows selected
    
SQL> insert into test (id, name, datum) values (1, 'Little', sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME                 DATUM
---------- -------------------- -------------------
         1 Little               01.11.2020 11:12:33

SQL>
```

Several minutes later:

```
SQL> select * from test order by datum;

        ID NAME                 DATUM
---------- -------------------- -------------------
         1 Little               01.11.2020 11:12:33
         2 Little               01.11.2020 11:14:36
         3 Little               01.11.2020 11:16:36

SQL>
```

So, yes - it is firing every 2 minutes and *does something*. See if it helps.